# R and factor coding in formula

Tags: r, formula, r-factor

How do I use the formula interface if I want custom valued dummies, e.g. if I want values 1 and two, rather than 0 and 1. The estimation might look like the following where `supp` is a factor variable.

```
fit <- lm(len ~ dose + supp, data = ToothGrowth)
```

In this example, there is not much use of the different values, but in many cases of a "re-written" model it can be useful.

EDIT: Actually, I have e.g. 3 levels, and want the two columns to be coded differently, so one is a 1/0 variable, and the other is a 1/2 variable. The above example only has two levels.

Comment: Depending on why you want to do this, setting the `contrasts` argument of `lm` may be sufficient.

Comment: I think that non of the default contrast methods give the coding I want.

Comment: You can names your factor levels whatever you want, e.g., `levels(supp) <- c("1", "2")`.  Much better to give them descriptive names though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the contrasts to be whatever you want by creating the matrix you want to use and setting it either to the `contrasts` argument of `lm` or setting the default contrast of the factor itself.

Some sample data:

```
set.seed(6)
d <- data.frame(g=gl(3,5,labels=letters[1:3]), x=round(rnorm(15,50,20)))
```

The contrasts you have in mind:

```
mycontrasts <- matrix(c(0,0,1,0,1,1), byrow=TRUE, nrow=3)
colnames(mycontrasts) <- c("12","23")
mycontrasts
#     12 23
#[1,]  0  0
#[2,]  1  0
#[3,]  1  1
```

Then you use this in the `lm` call:

```
> lm(x ~ g, data=d, contrasts=list(g=mycontrasts))

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ g, data = d, contrasts = list(g = mycontrasts))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          g12          g23  
       58.8        -13.6          5.8
```

We can check that it does the right thing by comparing the means:

```
> diff(tapply(d$x, d$g, mean))
    b     c 
-13.6   5.8
```

The default contrast is to use the first level as baseline:

```
> lm(x ~ g, data=d)

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ g, data = d)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           gb           gc  
       58.8        -13.6         -7.8
```

But that can be changed with the `contrasts` command:

```
> contrasts(d$g) <- mycontrasts
> lm(x ~ g, data=d)

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ g, data = d)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          g12          g23  
       58.8        -13.6          5.8
```

Comment: Fantastic, I don't know how I missed that. Didn't know you could just provide the definition as a matrix; thought it had to be a name of the coding schemes. Thanks.